# Pattern matching with a record in Oz

Tags: emacs, pattern-matching, records, oz, mozart

i'm having some trouble wrapping my head on how to utilize the elements of a record in Oz with pattern matching. Below is my code

```
declare
fun {Eval X E}
case X
of int(N) then N
   [] var(X) then E.X
   [] mul(X Y) then X*Y
   [] add(X Y) then X+Y
   end
   end
end

{Eval add(var(a) mul(int(3) var(b))) env(a:2 b:4)}
```

This is the input I have to utilize, the var(a) is supposed to return 2, (and var(b) return 4) from the env record in the input, I just cannot figure it out for anything.

Comment: In `mul(X Y) then X*Y`, you forgot to evaluate `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to call Eval recursively whenever you haven't reached a number or var. Try this instead:

```
declare
fun {Eval Node Env}
   if {IsNumber Node} then Node
   else
      case Node
      of var(X) then Env.X
      [] mul(X Y) then {Eval X Env} * {Eval Y Env}
      [] add(X Y) then {Eval X Env} + {Eval Y Env}
      end
   end
end
```

Additionally, Oz requires the return value of functions to be bound to a variable, so try something like:

```
declare
Ans = {Eval add(var(a) mul(3 var(b))) env(a:2 b:4)}
```

You can then view Ans with the Browser to verify the code is correct.